# how can i configure flycheck in vhdl code to recognize signals in packages

Tags: emacs, vhdl

I 'm trying to use emacs flycheck for vhdl coding environment. 
My problem is that flycheck cannot recognize packages and records in the packages and show warning such that "unit xx not found in library work"

I have also set  `(custom-set-variables '(flycheck-ghdl-workdir "/XXX/tWork/RTL/Mult/src/vhdl"))` to show the directory of the source code to the flycheck

[warning in emacs vhdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmIyy.png)

### How can i configure flycheck appropriately.

PS: below is new edit:

Let me clear this things first.

I have vhd file that includes a package as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.multPckg.all;

entity mutl is
  port(
    iClk  : in std_logic;
    iRst  : in std_logic;
    iData : in dataInRecord;
    );
end entity mutl;

architecture RTL of mutl is
  signal dataIni1 : dataInRecord := cDataInRecord;
  signal dataIni2 : dataInRecord := cDataInRecord;
  --signal x : std_logic;

begin

  --x <= osman;
  inRegPro : process (iClk) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(iClk) then
      dataIni1 <= iData;
      dataIni2 <= dataIni1;
    end if;
  end process inRegPro;

end architecture RTL;`
```

and the multPckg is in the same directory and coded by me

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package multPckg is
  constant dataInBitW  : integer := 8;
  constant dataOutBitW : integer := 8;

  type dataInRecord is record
    in1 : std_logic_vector(dataInBitW-1 downto 0);
    in2 : std_logic_vector(dataInBitW-1 downto 0);
  end record dataInRecord;
  constant cDataInRecord : dataInRecord := ((others => '0'), (others => '0'));

end package multPckg;

package body multPckg is

end package body multPckg;
```

emacs warn me about the line `use work.multPckg.all;` because of it cannot find the library work. Is there any way for emacs flycheck to find the `work.multPckg` not to give that warnings.

I hope i'm clear about the issue.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.2 Design libraries "A *design library* is an implementation-dependent storage facility for previously analyzed design units. A given implementation is required to support any number of design libraries." Determining the availability of declarations in a library are dependent on implementation (particular tool) features.  It seems you should be using the implementation to determine that.

Comment: I dont think your right about that it needs to compile code directory to reach to the packages. There are ide like products that does it seamlessly

Comment: Your question is not related to the VHDL language - as you are asking a question that is outside the VHDL spec. The source code could be in the same folder, a different drive, a different machine, or even another building.

Comment: My question is not related with the vhdl specification. It is the thing with the flycheck searching directory. How can i set this

Comment: `ghdl -a mutl.vhdl
mutl.vhdl:10:28:error: extra ';' at end of interface list
ghdl:error: compilation error`. This is in the port list for mutl. Removing the list item separator (';') before the ')' allows mutl to analyze.

Comment: The message in the bottom of your `warnings from emacs vhdl` linked image is actually an error message from ghdl `ghdl -a mutl.vhdl
mutl.vhdl:4:10:error: unit "multpckg" not found in library "work"` where ghdl is telling you that the package has not been analyzed into the library work. It'd not telling you it can't find library work.

Comment: how can i modify flycheck to analyze the package(multPckg) and clear the warning in the mult.vhd

Comment: The only place there's a correlation between the design file name and design units analyzed into resource library (here work) is in the .cf file. The package won't be in there before it's analyzed into the library. How could you possibly modify flycheck to analyze a design unit (package multpkgc) from a design file whose name isn't known? You can add all the design files to the library with ghdl's  import (-i) command and build with target with it's make (-m) command if you know the file names and target unit.

Comment: How can i more specific? But i will try. I want a basic vhdl linter with flycheck and emacs. Flycheck needs to find the problems of my code while I'm typing. Just a basic linter that is it

Comment: The problem is already stated. How can flycheck know where a package is located when the package name can be unrelated to the filename?

Comment: İs there a way to show flycheck packages?

Comment: At least [historically](https://gist.github.com/MasWag/4b74f9ac8f1014a73246) flycheck has no packages and modifies no library using the [-s command](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/InvokingGHDL.html?highlight=syntax#check-syntax-s). The package `multPckg` must have been previously analyzed into the work library for the syntax check of  design unit `mutl` to see the package declaration.

Comment: The newer [vhdl-ghdl checker](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/flycheck.el) (line 11143) uses the same `-s` command. You want the equivalent of an IDE which would import (`-i`) the files of a design and make (`-m`) a target., the equivalent of using a generated makefile.Then flycheck would have a working library and packages. Alternatively you could create a 'project' and share the library with the design. Doing so would be predicated on using ghdl as the project simulator.

Comment: There are semantic dependencies required by the VHDL standard in determining the validity of a design unit's description. That it hasn't been implemented in emacs is telling - it's outside the scope of a syntax checker. The rules for evaluating a prefix in a selected name (`work.multPckg.all`) are given in IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, 8.1. Without first analyzing the package into the work library at best the ghdl syntax check might have a clearer error message or explanatory documentation describing limitations.

Comment: There are tools that are library aware. See [VHDL-Tool Overview](https://www.vhdltool.com/configuration) (Libraries and see the configuration file) where an LSP is used along with proprietary code to enhance an editor (including emacs). It would have it's own libraries (and packages). ghdl has a language server as well.

Comment: i will try and let you know. Until that time i will accept your answer. @user1155120. thanks for your effort.